# How can I push all branch to a newly created repository?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, push, git-push

## Description

I have a **GitLab** repository with branch `dev`, `master`, and `github-snapshot` with **many** `tags`.

We want to go open source and we have written a **small script** that **creates the GitHub repository** and **push the whole project** on it.

The script **is run during a Gitlab-CI** and during this time, **the head** is on **detached state** using `${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}` (the commit hash).

Also, we want at the end the branch `github-snapshot` not to be puhsed on the GitHub repository.

After the GitHub repository creation, the script does in order:

1. create **new remote** `github`.
2. push all `branches` to `github`.
3. push all `tags` to `.github`
4. Delete branch `github-snapshot` from remote `github`.

### Reproduction

The step (2) is failing, this is how I do it

```
git -C ${path} push ${origin} --all
```

It produces the following error:

```
[ERROR]  Command failed: /bin/sh -c git -C /mnt/mesos/sandbox/builds/bootstrap-styled/navigation-bar push github --all
warning: refname '93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951' is ambiguous.
Git normally never creates a ref that ends with 40 hex characters
because it will be ignored when you just specify 40-hex. These refs
may be created by mistake. For example,

  git checkout -b $br $(git rev-parse ...)

where "$br" is somehow empty and a 40-hex ref is created. Please
examine these refs and maybe delete them. Turn this message off by
running "git config advice.objectNameWarning false"
remote: error: GH002: Sorry, branch or tag names consisting of 40 hex characters are not allowed.        
remote: error: Invalid branch or tag name "93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951"        
To https://[crypted]@github.com/bootstrap-styled/navigation-bar.git
 ! [remote rejected] 93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951 -> 93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951 (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] github-snapshot -> github-snapshot (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] gitlab-to-github -> gitlab-to-github (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://[crypted]@github.com/bootstrap-styled/navigation-bar.git'


[ERROR]  Command failed: /bin/sh -c git -C /mnt/mesos/sandbox/builds/bootstrap-styled/navigation-bar push github --all
warning: refname '93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951' is ambiguous.
Git normally never creates a ref that ends with 40 hex characters
because it will be ignored when you just specify 40-hex. These refs
may be created by mistake. For example,

  git checkout -b $br $(git rev-parse ...)

where "$br" is somehow empty and a 40-hex ref is created. Please
examine these refs and maybe delete them. Turn this message off by
running "git config advice.objectNameWarning false"
remote: error: GH002: Sorry, branch or tag names consisting of 40 hex characters are not allowed.        
remote: error: Invalid branch or tag name "93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951"        
To https://[crypted]@github.com/bootstrap-styled/navigation-bar.git
 ! [remote rejected] 93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951 -> 93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951 (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] github-snapshot -> github-snapshot (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] gitlab-to-github -> gitlab-to-github (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://[crypted]@github.com/bootstrap-styled/navigation-bar.git'
```

### Remark

For thoose who don't understand how `git push <remote> --all` can fail, I have added some log with `git branch -l`:

```
Remote github configured for GitHub.
Git branch list (git branch -l)
  93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951
  github-snapshot
  gitlab-to-github
* master
[ERROR]  Command failed: /bin/sh -c git -C /mnt/mesos/sandbox/builds/bootstrap-styled/navigation-bar push github --all
warning: refname '93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951' is ambiguous.
Git normally never creates a ref that ends with 40 hex characters
because it will be ignored when you just specify 40-hex. These refs
may be created by mistake. For example,
```

### Question

1. Considering I am in a detached state, how can I push all branch to a newly created repository?

My first idea was to checkout a real branch like `master`, but that would require another check to see if `master` is existing. I would like to be informed if there is a more appropriate way to do so.

Comment: You have created a very badly named branch, a branch named `93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951`. You should rename this branch to a more suitable name, e.g., `git branch -m 93a9252c263da35b2fdc6a7ca78ca18083ac5951 this-might-be-better`.

Answer (score 0):

To push all your branches, use either (replace REMOTE with the name of the remote, for example "origin"):

```
git push REMOTE '*:*'
git push REMOTE --all
To push all your tags:

git push REMOTE --tags
```

Finally, I think you can do this all in one command with:

```
git push REMOTE --mirror
```

However, in addition --mirror, will also push your remotes, so this might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: This is just exactly the same answer as the first google answer. The problem is this command can be run only from a branch otherwise it trys to push other than just branches.

Comment: @BigDong I don't understand, why would `git push <remote> --all` not work?

Comment: I've edited the question and added **Remark** for you

Answer (score 0):

As the error 'remote: error: GH002: Sorry, branch or tag names consisting of 40 hex characters are not allowed.' suggests Git creates issue in branches having names equal to 40 characters.
Rename your branch name having characters less than or greater than 40 (e.g. <=39 or >=41). You will never face this issue again.
We faced this issue when importing repo from one server to another using Azure import feature.